# Java and RegEx .. how to apply

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to do the following:

```
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
            }

            String data = sb.toString();

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\b[ABD-Z]*C[ABD-Z]*\b");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

            String a = m.group();
```

How do I access the results of `m`? Why is my RegEx not working?

I have tried escaping backslashes already.

It works on http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ but I can't get any output from Java.

Please help≥.. thanks.

Comment: My RegEx is designed to extract strings with one C in it.

Comment: This is already the third posting today for the same homework. You need to write `\\b` instead of `\b` unless you mean the backspace character.

Comment: Yes, embarrasing,... I guess I after spending a long time experimenting I just got annoyed. I still have plenty more work, but I won't use SO for it. Just needed a starter for 10. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 
m.find()
or
m.match()
most likely in a while loop.

```
while (m.find()) {
 do something with m.group()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you have to escape your backslashes to have a valid java string

you have to call `m.find()` before `m.group()`

Comment: Ok and how do I deal with multiple results?

Comment: as proposed by josh.trow simply loop until m.find() returns false

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\\b` instead of `\b` since the latter is a backspace and call `m.find()` if you're trying to match a substring or `m.match()` to match the whole string before calling `group()`.